# What is the top speed of the SR-72 aircraft? What affects would traveling at this speed have on the human body?

Tags: velocity, aircraft, biology

What is the top speed of the [SR-72](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_SR-72) aircraft? What affects would traveling at this speed have on the human body?

Comment: 1) < *What is the top speed of the SR72 aircraft?* > see specifications at http://www.giyf.com/sr72, 2) < *What affects would it have on the human body?* > speed does, other than acceleration, not have effects on the human (or any) body.

Comment: @СимонТыран Unless of course the pilot is forced to eject. Splat! :)

Comment: Also in this case it would only be the deceleration from the resisting air hitting the pilot that would hurt him, and deceleration is still acceleration just with a negative sign [:

Comment: In addition to the fact that this question appears to be off-topic, the tags do not fit at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about aviation & physiological effects of flight. Perhaps the [Aviation StackExchange Beta site](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1):

> What affects would traveling at this speed have on the human body?

The Earth revolves around the Sun at 18.5 miles per *second* and humans (as well as other living things) don't seem to notice.

In addition, the Sun is travelling around the Milky Way at 143 miles per *second*.

The astronauts and cosmonauts aboard the ISS are travelling at about 4.75 miles per *second* around the Earth and don't seem to notice.

What conclusion can we draw from the above facts?

Comment: + And the ISS folks step outside all the time.